# Piece of appscript code running slow? or is it Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this piece of code below that when it goes to find a value of a current cell the run time is about 6.87 sec. It is making the run time on my code about 7-8 seconds. It also seems like Google Sheets is buffering a lot longer after the code has run. I can't seem to speed either of them up.

For the code, I've rewritten the code a few times trying to put arrays where I can. I've added a data validation clear in hopes it would find the value faster. For the Google Sheets issues, I've tried clearing my cached data and tried two different browsers. None seemed to work

```
function onEdit () {
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ordersheet =data.getActiveSheet();
var reference = ordersheet.getSheetName();
var cleared = ordersheet.getActiveCell().clearDataValidations();

if(reference == "Order Sheet") { 

var ranged = ordersheet.getActiveRange();
var sheetName= ranged.getValue(); 
var pullName = data.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var datass = pullName.getRange(3, 1, pullName.getLastRow(), 
1).getValues();

var validationRule = 
SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation() 
.requireValueInList(datass).build(); 
ordersheet.getActiveCell().offset(1, 0, 
15).setDataValidation(validationRule);

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var off = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(1, 5).activate();
 var row = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getRow();
 var col = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getColumn();

  var formulas = [

 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-1]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
  INDIRECT(R[-1]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
  List")'],
  ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-2]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
  INDIRECT(R[-2]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
  List")'],
 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-3]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
 INDIRECT(R[-3]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
 List")'],
 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-4]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
 INDIRECT(R[-4]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
 List")'], 
 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-5]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
 INDIRECT(R[-5]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
  List")'], 
 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-6]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
 INDIRECT(R[-6]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
 List")'],
 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-7]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
 INDIRECT(R[-7]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
  List")'],
  ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-8]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
  INDIRECT(R[-8]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
  List")'],
  ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-9]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
  INDIRECT(R[-9]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
   List")'],
 ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-10]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
 INDIRECT(R[-10]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
  List")'],
  ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-11]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
   INDIRECT(R[-11]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
   List")'],
  ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-12]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
   INDIRECT(R[-12]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
    List")'],
  ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-13]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
  INDIRECT(R[-13]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
    List")'],
   ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-14]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
   INDIRECT(R[-14]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer Price 
    List")'],
    ['=Iferror(INDEX(INDIRECT(R[-15]C[-5]&1),MATCH(R[0]C[-5],
    INDIRECT(R[-15]C[-5]&2),0),2),"Please Add Item to Customer 
     Price List")']
    ];
   var area = spreadsheet.getRange(row,col,15);
   area.setFormulasR1C1(formulas);

      }};
```

The code works for how the sheet is set up but I just need it to run faster.

Comment: Yes, writing formulas out to a sheet can be a little time consuming but I think your doing it about as fast as you can.  I find that users tend to overuse the onEdit functionality.  Remember, this is running on a server.

Comment: would you suggest I try to change the onedit function to call when I need it only?

Comment: That would normally be my approach because I don't like to waste server resources frivolously and clicking button especially in a sidebar is no big deal.  But it's your choice.

Comment: Thank you @Cooper Really appreciate the feed back!. I took it out of the the onEdit and it is running faster but still buffering oddly slow in google sheets. If there are any more suggestions I will gladly use them!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but try putting SpreadsheetApp.flush() at the end.